# Why do we need to perform topological ordering first to find shortest path in a weighted DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, topological-sort

My textbook has an excerpt that says one should perform topological sorting to get the vertices in order before finding the shortest path between s and t:

[image]

I don't understand *why* this is a necessary step to find the shortest path in a weighted DAG. **Can't we just start at s, and use BFS to explore its neighbors, recording the minimum distance to each vertex?**

Or in other words: **What would happen if we tried to find the shortest path without first performing topological ordering?**

Comment: FWIW, I don't see in this excerpt where it explicitly says that you _must_ do a topological sort first.

Comment: Sure, it's either topological sorting OR DFS in reversal of G and considering vertices in postorder. My question is why do we need to this vertex ordering?

Answer (score 1):

I was earlier too confused that why one cannot do simple bfs/dfs for getting single source shortest distance. But after so much research, my doubt has resolved and therefore I am here for pulling you out of this trouble.

Simple bfs/dfs will work absoluety fine in most cases but not in all cases.
For instance, try to find answer using simple bfs/dfs(source is 0).Find distances from 0 to all nodes.

```
ADJ LIST:
    N W
0->[1,5][2,2]
1->[3,1]
2->[1,1][3,7] 

                                                           N=NODE
                                                           W=WEIGHT TO 
                                                             REACH THERE
```

Your answer will be-[0,3,2,6] which is not correct.
Why the test case failed?

Here we created a queue and pushed 0 ,updated its distance as 0 and through adjacency list found its neighbours which are 1 and 2 ,updated dist as 5 and 2 respectively,pushed them in queue.
Then went to 1,found its neighbours which is 3, updated dist  as dist[1]+weight[1][3]=5+1=6.Pushed 3 in queue.
Then went to 2(present in queue)updated distance of 1 as dist[2]+weight[2][1]=3 .Checked dist of 3 as dist[2]+weight[2][3]=2+7=9,as the dist was greater than previous dist we do not updated it.But here we missed that dist of 1 has changed and because of that dist of all nodes attached to 1 has changed but we haven't done that.

Thus it is important to note that topological sort will ensure that if u->v, u should be computed before v which will update distance of v every time when prev dist[v]> dist[u]+weight to reach there.Hence will get correct shortest distance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a vertex *u* that is in a topoligically sorted sequence. Topoligical sorting guarantees that every incoming edge to *u* is already considered, therefore we already know the shortest path to *u* and now we are able to find the shortest path to the next vertex and so on till the bottom vertex will be reached.